# Numpy.ma polyfit function for masked arrays crashes on integer input

Tags: numpy, curve-fitting, polynomial-math, maskedinput

The numpy polynomial fit function for masked arrays, `ma.polyfit`, crashes on integer iput:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
x = ma.arange(2)
y = ma.arange(2)
p1 = ma.polyfit(np.float32(x), y, deg=1)
p2 = ma.polyfit(           x , y, deg=1)
```

The last line results in an error:

```
ValueError: data type <type 'numpy.int64'> not inexact
```

Why can't I fit data with integer x-values (it's no problem with the normal `numpy.polyfit` function), is this a (known) bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a bug from `numpy.ma` : the `rcond` (a parameter to exclude some values ) takes `len(x)*np.finfo(x.dtypes).eps` as a default value, and `np.int32` does not have any `eps`field (because an int does not have a relative precision).

```
import numpy.ma as ma
eps = np.finfo(np.float32).eps 

x = ma.arange(2)
y = ma.arange(2)
p1 = ma.polyfit(np.float32(x), y, deg=1, rcond = len(x)*eps)
p2 = ma.polyfit(           x , y, deg=1, rcond = len(x)*eps)
```

I've looked quickly into numpy's issues, and this bug does not seems to figured there. It might be a good idea to raise a new issue : [New Issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/new)

Comment: Thanks for reassuring, I have submitted a new issue.

Comment: BTW, instead of `import np.finfo(np.float32).eps as eps`, I guess you meant `eps = np.finfo(np.float32).eps` ...? :-)

Comment: it's identical : it's a question of style :p

Comment: That's curious: `import np.finfo(np.float32).eps as eps` gives me a syntax error ...

Comment: oups you're right : I didn't run this part of the code. I fix it immediately.